# Hide "Ship to a different address" for a specific user role in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, user-roles

Plugin used: "User Role editor" to add extra roles.

Created a role: "SpecialCust"

I have tried to unset "ship to different address" if user has this roll but it's not really picking up the code as it seems.

```
function Unset_Shipping_adress() {
    // Get the user object.
    $user = get_userdata( $user_id );

    // Get all the user roles as an array.
    $user_roles = $user_meta->roles;

    // Check if the role you're interested in, is present in the array.
    if ( in_array( 'SpecialCust', $user_roles, true ) ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some missing parts in your code and it can be simplified. Try the following instead:

```
add_action('init', 'unset_shipping_address' );
function unset_shipping_address() {
    // HERE the targeted user roles
    $user_roles = array('SpecialCust', 'SpecialCust2', 'SpecialCust3');

    // Check user roles to hide “Ship to a different address”
    foreach( $user_roles as $user_role ) {
        if ( current_user_can( sanitize_title( $user_role ) ) ) {
            add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
            break; // Found, we stop the loop
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

> **Reminder:** to hide “Ship to a different address” in Woocommerce we just use:
>
> ```
> add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_shipping_address', '__return_false');
> ```

Comment: I am not sure If I am allowed to "add to my question" but: If I want to add several roles, Like if user is SpecialCust, if user is Specialcust2, do I just add a comma to seperate?

Comment: @ErikaJohansson Updated (but not tested) … Try that new code version and tel me… It should work.

Comment: Sure did! Thank you for the help.